# In this code below, I can't seem to place the text right next to the image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="row row-content align-iterms-center">
            <div class="row row-content align-iterms-center">
            
                <div class="col col-sm-6 order-sm-first col-md">
                  <div class="col-sm">
                      <div class="card">
                        <h3 class="card-header bg-danger text-white">District Hospital Blood Bank Udupi</h3>
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <dl class="row-content">
                              <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
                            <dt class="col-12 col-sm-3 "><img src="/images/blood-donate.jpg" height="200" width="240"></dt>
                          </div><h4><dd class="col-12 col-sm"><br><span class="fa fa-map-marker"> Kinnimulki, Udupi</span><br>
                              District Hospital Blood Bank is located at NA in the Udupi district of Karnataka. 
                              Phone number, contact email and website address if available is provided above in the blood bank vital information section. Please refer to the location on Map if you want to visit this blood bank right now.</h4></dd>             
                          </dl></div>
                      </div></div>
                    </div>
                  
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hello. Please post a snippet of your HTML and CSS (CTRL + M while editing).

Answer (score 2):

In order to have text on the left or right of the image you can style your img as `style="float:left";` or `style="float:right";` If the text is too close to the image you can play with padding: 10px; or less. More info [here](http://codecademy.com/forum_questions/51acec89324e0ccf6d00010f#51acfa44c7e65d7e9c00007d)